# How to set the username to display in Home frame

Tags: java

In my question, i have separate jframes created using netbeans. one is log in frame with textfield to enter username and a password field. Once logged in you go to the next frame, home. Now i placed a label there on the home frame to show the name of the logged user. Now i want to know how to get the username applied in login box to display in this label. Thanks in advance.. Any help on this is hugely appreciated. Thanks.
I want to get logged username from log in frame to display in home frame.
I tried the following code. But it's not working for me.

```
 public String getMainText() {
return txt_user.getText();
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a bit more code? I.e. the actual classes of the login frame and its subcomponents?

Comment: In my question, i have separate jframes created i netbeans. one is log in frame with textfield to enter username and a password field. Once logged in you go to the next frame, home. Now i placed a label there on the home frame to show the name of the logged user. Now i want to know how to get the username applied in login box to display in this label. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could create something like a "Data" Class where you safe the recent user and stuff like this. Then you give the same instance from this Data class to both of your frames and can then enter the data instance to get your username.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways (if I understood your question correctly, which is a big if...)

First (and I suppose best) one would be to pass the value to the new frame in the constructor

```
MyFrame MyframeObject = new MyFrame(Username);
```

You just need to add this in your own JFrame Class

Other than that you could make the Username variable public  or create a getter method if the previous frame still exists

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more. In my question, i have separate jframes created i netbeans. one is log in frame with textfield to enter username and a password field. Once logged in you go to the next frame, home. Now i placed a label there on the home frame to show the name of the logged user. Now i want to know how to get the username applied in login box to display in this label. Thanks in advance.